# Program to concatenate two strings in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Please note: I am aware the program may have multiple errors and it is not well written, I am just trying to learn

My program is concatenate two strings in 8086, my code is :-

```
printmsg macro ms
mov ah,09h
lea dx,ms
int 21h
endm
printip macro ms
mov ah,09h
lea dx,ms+2
int 21h
endm
ipuser macro ms
mov ah,0ah
lea dx,ms
int 21h
endm
code segment
assume cs:code, ds:data
mov dx,data
mov ds,dx
printmsg ms1
ipuser input1
printmsg ms2
ipuser input2
lea si,input1+2
up: cmp [si],byte ptr '$'
je done
inc si
jmp up
done: lea di,input2+2
lbl: mov dl,[di]
mov [si],dl
cmp [si],byte ptr '$'
je endpr
inc di
inc si
loop lbl
endpr: printmsg ms3
printmsg nl
printip input1
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
code ends
data segment
ms1 db 10,13,'Enter first string:$'
ms2 db 10,13,'Enter second string:$'
ms3 db 10,13,'Concatenated string is:$'
nl db 0dh,0ah,'$'
input1 db 10 dup('$')
input2 db 10 dup('$')
data ends
end
```

The output I am getting is :-

`Enter first string:mihir
Enter second string:kandoi
Concatenated string is:
kandoi`

The output I desire is :-

`Enter first string:mihir
Enter second string:kandoi
Concatenated string is:
mihirkandoi`

What seems to be the problem? I am new to strings

Comment: Please try to follow some coding standards when writing code, especially assembly. In you example it would be really helpful if you separate the functions with empty lines and use indendation with labels.

Comment: Looks like wall of text .. not going to read into that. Try to reformat it, use some empty lines to group logical parts together, use indentation to differentiate instructions from label (it's ~40 years old habit to have labels starting in first column, and instruction indent at least at column 4 or even more, you may be not used to it, but almost everyone else is, just check some assembly examples to get idea what reads good and use that).

Answer (score 1):

Your program looks fine, except for the use of the `loop` instruction for which you didn't setup the necessary CX register! Moreover you don't need this instruction in this code.

```
lbl:
    mov al,[di]
    mov [si],al
    cmp al, '$'
    je  endpr
    inc di
    inc si
    jmp lbl      <-- Change LOOP into JMP
endpr:
```

Although this modification/correction is an important one, it should not cure the output. I suspect you got some kind of a typo in your original program source.